# Skipping instructions during input

Tags: c

I have a small console program. I am trying to get user input like this:

```
char host_ip[16];
int length = 0;
/* Get host ip */
while(length < 7){
     printf("Input host ip (Max: 15) ");
     length = getstring(host_ip, 16);
     if(length < 7)
         printf("Host ip can't be less then 7 symbols\n");
}
length = 0;

/*getstring: read string to 'line' and return length*/
int getstring(char *line, int max){

    int c, i;

    for(i = 0; i < max - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++)
        *line++ = c;

    *line = '\0';

    return i;
}
```

When I input `host_ip` more than 14 symbols, some instructions going after this instruction are being just skipped, but if `host_ip` is less than 14 symbols then all are working.
[image]

[image]

I can’t understand why this is happening? Because in my opinion, the pointer should stop at "max -1" and add "\0" at the end

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Then nothing is read, more ideally even if the input is more than 15 characters, the line should still only accept 15 characters. Other instructions accept input to other variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you input 15 characters and press Enter, 16 characters (assuming Unix environment) are sent to input stream of your program - input and newline character.

Your stream after this input looks like this (I'm using `⏎` for newline):

```
111.111.111.111⏎
^ <- next read marker
```

You call your `getstring` function, which reads 15 characters from stream as expected.
`host_ip` now contains `111.111.111.111\0`, perfect. But now, you call `getstring` again, and it starts reading from the same buffer.

```
111.111.111.111⏎
               ^ <- next read marker
```

First character read is `\n` (`⏎`), which makes the third part of your condition false. Your loop stops, `\0` is appended to `line`, function returns.
Stream state now:

```
111.111.111.111⏎
                ^ <- next read marker
```

Since the stream is now empty (no character ready to be read), execution stops and waits until data is ready in the stream (user inputs something). Your third call to `getstring` works correctly.

---

I don't know C, but [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) looks like it's doing exactly what you are trying (though it adds newline character at the end of the string, you'd have to remove it).
Or `scanf` has option to read up to first whitespace or number of characters.
Or, if you want to stick with your implementation, you have to discard characters up until newline character or EOF.